# What is the equivalent of PHP's preg_quote?

Tags: c#

What is the equivalent of PHP's [preg_quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)?

This is as far as I have gotten for creating a method that extracts text from a string:

```
    public static string f_get_string_between(string text, string start, string end)
    {
        //both these attempts below throw an unrecognized escape sequence error
        //start = "\Q"+start+"\E";
        //end = "\Q"+end+"\E"; 

        Regex regex = new Regex(start + "(.*?)" + end);
        var v = regex.Match(text);
        text = v.Groups[1].ToString();
        return text;
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx)

Comment: Regex.Escape is close but it seems to behave slightly different in certain scenarios. In particular, it doesn't escape "]" characters which may or may not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct replacement for `preg_quote` in C# but you could write your own function to do just that. From the PHP manual, the characters that are escaped by the function are: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -` so you would just write a function that takes a string, and escapes any of these characters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx)?